# На SSD не форматируется Ext4 в NTFS

Tags: windows, format, ssd, ntfs, ext4

На свежий SSD ставил Manjaro Linux, после решил вернуться на Windows 10. Установщик винды "удаляет" старые разделы линукса (делаю я это с целью "чистой" установки), но на самом деле ничего не происходит - сразу же после успешной операции показывается ровно та же картина, два раздела - EFI и "неизвестный". Через другой компьютер с десяткой пробовал Paragon Disk Manager, стандартный Disk Managment и diskpart, все способы так же "удаляют" разделы, форматируют диск под NTFS, но после обновления актуального состояния (refresh/F5) картина остается той же - один раздел FAT32 на 300мб (EFI) и оставшееся место под EXT4.

SSD Silicon Power A58, диск Surface Test в MiniTool Partition Wizard проходит, пробовал монтировать раздел данных через Ext2Fsd, в проводнике винды диск показался, попросил себя отформатировать, выбрал NTFS, операция прошла неудачно.

Суть проблемы - диском воспользоваться никоим образом не удается, он вроде и жив, но никакими средствами форматироваться не хочет, не дает установиться винде и нет доступа через проводник.

Comment: Конвертацию в MBR через diskpart я уже пробовал  и результата это не дало, диск не конвертируется.

Answer (score 3):

Тогда решение через загрузочный диск Linux. Любой.
Запускаем GParted удаляем все разделы какие есть. Ничего после этого не форматируем и не создаем.
После чего в установщике Windows разбиваем и форматируем диск как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Запусти CMD от имени админа или нажми F8 когда в winpe систему загрузишь.
запусти diskpart попробуй набрать list disk

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Диск ###  Состояние      Размер   Свободно Дин  GPT
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Диск 0    В сети         2794 Gбайт  1024 Kбайт        *
  Диск 1    В сети          238 Gбайт    17 Mбайт        *
  Диск 2    В сети            8 Gбайт  1024 Kбайт
```

найди номер диска, который соответствует твоему SSD, и попробуй набрать ( 0 желаемый диск )

```
select disk 0  
clean  
convert mbr
```